# Is there a way to show roads connected but keep them on separate layers (with separate markings, line styles etc.)?

Tags: qgis-2

In QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour, is there a way to connect different layer roads? Say i have 2 kinds of roads on 2 layers. One is main roads, the other is smaller ones. At the moment they go over each other depending on which of the layers is over another. Is there a way to somehow connect them but keep them on separate layers (with separate markings, line styles etc.)?

Comment: is question about how to fix network topology or howto draw nice looking map?

Comment: The second one - a nice looking map

Comment: Are you asking about snapping lines to lines?  If so, then you can set that in the Snapping Tolerance window.  You can choose what layer you want to snap to.  Part of it does sound like network topology, as roads should not cross roads, unless they are a fly-over highway.

Comment: Why do you want to keep separate layers? Any reason besides styling?

Comment: No other reason, they need to appear different on a map (differrent width, color)

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like an TYPE on both shapefiles it is easy:

merge both shapefiles to one using vector-data management tools-merge shapefiles to one.

Add the resulting shapefile to the map and use categorized in the layer properties dialog and use the TYPE to determine the symbol.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the styling of those previously separate shapefiles?

Comment: unfortunately you will loose them, but I think you can probably save the symbol-stile of the and reuse them in the new merged shapefile for each class of roads.

Comment: OK, this is becoming a full on discussion, but one more question: how do i apply differrent styles to differrent classes on the same shapefile?

Comment: change this to fit the needs of your line shapefile: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-styling-vector-data-in-qgis.html